# Problems when running or debugging application

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-manifest

Normally when I run or debugg my application, it unistalls the old version, installs new version and finally it runs the new application, same process when I debug. Some days ago my eclipse started to work in a different way, it installs my application but it does not get ran. Before intalling I get this LogCat:

```
    No Launcher activity found!
    The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Here my Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.company.app.activities.WelcomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Can anybody help me with this? If I want to run the applications it's not a problem because I just have to do it manually but I can not debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the follwing line from your manifest and try ,

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

Comment: Ok, I have removed this line and now it is working. It is really weird because It was working before with this sentence. Anyway, thanxs a lot.